# ¿como ordenar asc solo los checkbox que estan seleccionados?

Tags: php, javascript, array, checkbox

Hola necesito de su valiosa ayuda les planteo la situacio tengo una tabla con 4 campos de los cuales uno es un checkbox (campo seleccionar)
Algunos campos checkbox ya estan seleccionados por defecto, y estan desordenados.
lo que necesito hacer es ordenar al principio solo los seleccionados y los que estan desmarcados hasta el final
Este es el codigo:

```
input#buscarUA.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Escribe el texto a encontrar', style='width:25%;')
        br

        table#tablausuariosagregar.table.table-bordered.table-hover(data-toggle='table', data-query-params='queryParams', data-pagination='false', data-search='false', data-height='400')
          thead(style="font-size:12px;background-color:rgb(233,236,239);")
            tr
              th Seleccionar 
              th Perfil
              th Nombre
              th Cuenta

          tbody
            each usuario,index in datos.usuarios
              tr(style='background-color:243,243,243;font-size:12px;')
                td
                  input#checkusers(data-perfil=''+usuario.perfil,onclick="get_values_usuarios_seleccionados();",class='check_user',type='checkbox', value='#{usuario.pk}')
                td #{usuario.perfil}
                td #{usuario.nombre}
                td #{usuario.cuenta}
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stackoverflow en español @Karime Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Comment: Buscas una respuesta en javascript o php? que probaste en esos lenguajes? donde esta ese codigo? cuales son los chekcbox que queres ordenar?

Comment: eso de php no tiene nada. A mí me parece que es una plantilla HAML

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Esta es una solución simple y burda: cada vez que pinchas un checkbox, si lo activaste mueves toda su fila al inicio de la tabla. Si lo desactivaste mueves toda su fila al final de la tabla.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.casilla').click(function() {
      var $this=$(this),
          fila=$this.closest('tr'),
          tbody=$this.closest('tbody')
      if($this.is(':checked')) {
         fila.prependTo(tbody);
      } else {
         fila.appendTo(tbody);
      }
  });

});
```

```css
table td, table th {
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<table>
 <thead>
 <tr>
    <th>Checkbox</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Raza</th>
    <th>Edad</th>
    <th>Dueño</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="casilla" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Knocky</td>
    <td>Jack Russell</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>Juan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="casilla" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Flor</td>
    <td>Poodle</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Pedro</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input class="casilla" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Sultán</td>
    <td>Labrador</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Diego</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="casilla" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>Rocky</td>
    <td>Bulldog</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Alicia</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

La manera más elegante sería usando `sort` y ordenar tanto los checkeados como los no chequeados por una propiedad (por ejemplo alfabéticamente según la columna "nombre", pero eso te lo dejo de tarea